# php login page issue

Tags: php, mysql

i'm creating a php login page. i can't get the page to redirect (to index.php in this case) when the $_SESSION variable "success" is passed. I can get the success message to work so I think my form and query are fine. What am I missing here?

Here's the form (login.php):

```
<? $page = "login-page";//body tag class

$title = "Log in to your Bloggr Account";//title tag text

session_start();

require_once('includes/header.php');

print_r($_SESSION); ?>

<p class="errors" id="errors">

<? if(!empty($_SESSION['errors'])){ ?>

     <script type="text/javascript"> $(function() {

           setTimeout(function(){

          $("#errors").fadeIn(500);}, 500)});

     <script>

<? foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $error){
        echo $error;}
        session_unset($_SESSION['errors']);
    } ?>
</p> <? if(!empty($_SESSION['success'])){

    header("Location: index.php");
    echo $success;
    session_unset($_SESSION['success']); } ?>
<form action="login-post2.php" method="post" class="admin-form login">
<label for="userName">User Name <label>
<input type="text" name="userName" class="user-name" value="" />
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" class="password" />
<input type="submit" class="submit" name="register-submit" value="Log In!" />
</form>
```

Here is the post file (login-post2.php)

```
<? if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    session_start();
    require_once('../_db_connect.php');
    $errors = array();
    $success = "You're logged in!";
    if(empty($_POST['userName'])){
    $errors[] = "Please enter a user name.";
    }else[
    $userName = $_POST["userName"];
}

if(empty($errors)){
    $query = "SELECT userName, password FROM users WHERE userName = '$userName' and password = SHA1('$password')";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);
    if(!result){
        $errors[] = "Please try again!";
} else{
    $success;
}
}

$_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
$_SESSION['success'] = $success;

exit();
} ?>
```

Sorry if some of the formatting is a bit off.

****EDIT [SOLVED]***
for anyone who comes across this in the future here's what i did. here's where the biggest part of my problem was:

```
if(empty($errors)){
        $query = "SELECT userName, password FROM users WHERE userName = '$userName' and password = SHA1('$password')";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query);     
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){//if username and password match;
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = $loggedIn;      
            header("Location: index.php");
            exit();
        }                   
    } else{
        $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
    }
```

I didn't do a good job of formatting my if/else statement for $errors. Part of my problem, which I knew at the time but couldn't figure out, was that I needed a way to send headers twice. one way if i had $errors and another way if i didn't. the way i had before was trying to send it twice without a conditional. my solution was to wrap the last bit of my statement as the else which allowed me to send the user back to the login page if there were errors and over to the index page if they were successfully logged in. That's it. Hope this helps others in the future.

Comment: Please, for the sake of Dearth (respect) and the rest fo us, post your code using the mark-down technique :)

Comment: @nickhar, I know. I am ashamed. I rarely post code on here.

Comment: Don't be ashamed - just cut and paste - rather than using <code> tags. :) and while I'm at it, you should post you're code MORE on here and for the benefit of YOU!

Comment: @nickhar, i figured out my problem and posted the solution in proper code. just thought you should know, i've learned my lesson. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `header()` [before you send any other content](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) (either through some PHP thing like `echo` or `var_dump()` or just HTML between PHP tags).

You're sending out:

```
<p class="errors" id="errors">
<script type="text/javascript"> $(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
    $("#errors").fadeIn(500);}, 500)});
<script>

echo $error;}

</p>
```

before you send the headers.  Refactor your code to move the call to `header()` before these.

Comment: you mean before i send any other content on login.php?

Comment: Yeah.  Check my above code.  You may just want to move the check to before any of the error stuff.

Answer (score 0):

`header("Location: login.php);`

Missing a quote could be a problem.

Comment: sorry, that is in the original code. I just left it out of the submission.